# Connect postman from an RDP windows 10 client back to a node web restapi running on the macbook pro host?

Tags: node.js, postman, rdp

I am trying to run postman in a windows 10 RDP client, and I want to test a node application running on the host computer.  The host is a macbook pro and the application is running on localhost:3000 there.  I can't simply use https://localhost:3000 in postman, because localhost there is for that machine.  Is there a way?

Comment: SImple answer: No.

Comment: @Marc, yeah, I'm coming to that realization.

Comment: Why the overhead with the RDP session? Just use postman on the macbook directly.

Comment: @Marc - The actual work I have to do is there and finished on the remote machine.  It calls a web service elsewhere on our network.  But I am blocked atm as it has not been written yet.  In my down time, I thought of trying this kind of testing it with a home-grown nodejs restapi I have written locally.  I guess I'll have to be patient ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that it might be a big security hole.  The more I think about it, the more I see a problem with it.  I mean, I can share folders - as you do - but that is pretty controlled.  I could well be wrong though